# Хук состояния не изменяет состояние, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Есть страница создания новости, при отправке формы, на сервер приходит объект такого типа:

```
{
   title: 'текст примера',
   text: 'текст примера'
}
```

хотя он должен быть таким:

```
{
   title: 'текст примера',
   text: 'текст примера',
   posted: {
       fullDate: "9 сентября 2020 г., 21:56:36",
       timestamp: 1599681396,
       timeZone: 2,
       year: "2020",
       month: "9",
       day: "9",
       hour: "21",
       minutes: "56",
       seconds: "36"
   }
}
```

Что я делаю не так? Может я не правильно использую хуки состояния?

И ещё по приходу успешного ответа с сервера input[name="title"] почему-то не хочет отчищаться...

Страница создания новости:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import classes from './CreateNews.module.scss';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { createPostedTime } from '../../functions';
import { createPost } from '../../posts';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import UserForm from '../../components/UI/UserForm/UserForm';
import GoBackToAdmin from '../../components/UI/GoBackToAdmin/GoBackToAdmin';

const CreateNews = () => {
    const [post, setPost] = useState({
        title: '',
        text: ''
    });

    const changeTitleHandler = (e) => {
        setPost({
            ...post,
            title: e.target.value
        });
    }

    const changeTextHandler = (e) => {
        setPost({
            ...post,
            text: e
        });
    }

    const submitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        setPost({
            ...post,
            posted: createPostedTime()
        });
        
        try {
            await createPost(post).then((res) => {
                setPost({
                    title: '',
                    text: ''
                });
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={classNames('container', classes.CreateNews)}>
            <GoBackToAdmin />
            <UserForm
                title={post.title}
                text={post.text}
                buttonText="Создать новость"
                changeTitle={changeTitleHandler}
                changeText={changeTextHandler}
                onSubmit={submitHandler}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default CreateNews;
```

Код компонента UserForm:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './UserForm.module.scss';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import Input from '../Input/Input';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';

const modules = {
    toolbar: [
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
        ['blockquote', 'code-block'],

        [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
        [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
        [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
        [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
        [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

        [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
        [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

        [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
        [{ 'font': [] }],
        [{ 'align': [] }],

        ['image', 'video'],

        ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
    ]
};

const UserForm = ({title, text, buttonText, changeTitle, changeText, onSubmit}) => {
     

    return (
        <form className={classNames(classes.UserForm)}>
            <Input
                className={classes.UserForm__Title}
                title="Название новости"
                placeholder="Введите название новости..."
                type="text"
                name="title"
                value={title}
                onChange={changeTitle}
            />
            <div className={classNames(classes.FormControl)}>
                <label htmlFor="text">
                    Контент новости
                </label>
                <ReactQuill 
                    id="text"
                    modules={modules} 
                    theme="snow" 
                    value={text} 
                    onChange={changeText}
                />
            </div>
            <button
                type="submit"
                className={classNames('btn', classes.UserForm__SubmitBtn)}
                onClick={onSubmit}
            >
                {buttonText}
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default UserForm;
```

Функция createPostedTime():

```
export function createPostedTime() {
    const date = new Date();
    const timeZone = -date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    const fullDate = {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric',
        second: 'numeric'
    };
    const year = {
        year: 'numeric',
    }
    const month = {
        month: 'numeric',
    }
    const day = {
        day: 'numeric',
    }
    const hour = {
        hour: 'numeric',
    }
    const minutes = {
        minute: 'numeric',
    }
    const seconds = {
        second: 'numeric'
    }

    const posted = {};

    function timeSave(named, item) {
        posted[named] = date.toLocaleString("ru", item);
    }

    timeSave('fullDate', fullDate);
    timeSave('year', year);
    timeSave('month', month);
    timeSave('day', day);
    timeSave('hour', hour);
    timeSave('minutes', minutes);
    timeSave('seconds', seconds);
    posted.timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    posted.timeZone = timeZone;

    return posted;
}
```

Comment: А покажите функцию createPostedTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setPost` работает асинхронно, и `createPost(post)` получает старую версию (от последнего рендера).

Можно использовать `const postToSend = {...post,` .

---

Или можно делать пост из `useEffect`, но тут важно не зациклить.

И вообще форма `setPost(wasPost=>({...wasPost,title}))` безопаснее.

Comment: Спасибо, так я и поступил, но не могу понять, почему при положительном ответе с сервера у меня не отчищается инпут, но когда это был классовый компонент, то при простом изменении состояния всё чистилось спокойно...

Comment: так не видно ... можете новый вопрос делать, с новым кодом; в т. ч. createPost